# Restoring SQL transaction backups without last full BAK file

Tags: sql-server, backup

Currently I'm trying to restore a SQL Server 2014 database by restoring latest transaction (TRN) backup files since the last full back-up.

Back-ups made (automated by maintenance plan jobs):

```
05-11-2016 @ 21.00h : Full BAK (no copy-only)
06-11-2016 @ 04.40h : Full BAK (no copy-only, but no BAK file available)
06-11-2016 @ 06.00h : Transaction log TRN (no copy-only)
06-11-2016 @ 07.00h : Transaction log TRN (no copy-only)
06-11-2016 @ 08.00h : Transaction log TRN (no copy-only)
06-11-2016 @ 09.00h : Transaction log TRN (no copy-only)
```

My goal is to restore my database to the latest transaction log back-up, created on 06-11-2016 @ 09.00h

However, as listed above, the latest full BAK back-up is missing because the back-up was made by an 3rd party back-up software. This software only gives us an option to restore the full back-up of 06-11-2016 @ 04:40h as MDF and LDF data and log files.

Since the back-up, made by that 3rd party software, broke the LSN sequence I am NOT able to restore my latest TRN transaction back-up since the referenced BAK is missing.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

For example:

- Option 1: when I attach the `.MDF` and `.LDF` files made by the 3rd party software, put the database in restoring state so I can restore my transaction TRN back-up files?
- Option 2: use the previous full `.BAK` back-up (05-11-2016 @ 21.00h) and after restore, restore the transaction TRN back-ups

I'm afraid both options are no solution with out-of-the-box options in SQL Server 2014.

Maybe there are any alternatives? Maybe other software to resolve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have all of the log backups from your November 5 full backup forward? If so, restore that full backup and all of the log backup up to the point in time you want to restore to.

Comment: Unfortunately there were no LOG backups made between the first and seond full BAK backups :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, that November 6 backup. It's odd to me though that the third party software only gives you the option of restoring the full backup and no log backups.

Comment: Please have a look on this thread http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-restore-database-using-old-full-backup-and-current-log-file